# SMBus v1.1 voltage threshhold value

Tags: pic, i2c, smbus

I am planning to use PIC18F26K83 and communicate with a smart battery that uses SMBus ver 1.1. So from the datasheet of PIC it says I need to choose appropriate input threshhold for SMBus from RxyI2C register. Bit 0 and 1 are being used for choosing that threshold but there is no information for SMBus ver 1.1 (See below.).

> TH<1:0>: I2C Input Threshold Selection bits
>
> 11 = SMBus 3.0 (1.35 V) input threshold
>
> 10 = SMBus 2.0 (2.1 V) input threshold
>
> 01 = I2C specific input thresholds
>
> 00 = Standard GPIO Input pull-up, enabled via INLVLxy registers

And over the internet I couldn't find input threshold for SMBus v1.1. So my question is:

What is the input threshold voltage for SMBus v1.1? Or how should I set related bits in order to use SMBus v1.1 from RxyI2C register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the input threshold voltage for SMBus v1.1?

It is 2.1 V just like SMBus v2.0. Here is an extract of the [SMBus v1.1 specification](http://smbus.org/specs/smbus110.pdf) confirming this:

[image: SMBus v1.1 DC parameters]

<sub>(Image source: [Section 8.2.1 SMBus v1.1 specification](http://smbus.org/specs/smbus110.pdf))</sub>